# How do I collect strings from a number of users?

Tags: android, mysql, sql-server-2008, cloud

I'm creating a basic app for about only 100 users. When the user clicks a button I want the app to send a string to some online database. Pretty much attendance collection. Ideally, everyone's app could append their unique string to a text file which I could then download and use as I want.

I really don't know where to begin. It's not worth purchasing a server for. I'd like to use GoogleDrive or DropBox, but with many people simultaneously performing the same action, the cloud doesn't seem ideal.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? A few keywords should be all that I need.

Comment: this looks like you do need a server for that. there are free versions available. Also, why is your question tagged with `mysql` and `sql-server`, if you do not intend to have such server ? Also, what do you intent to do with that file?

Comment: and what would you expect to happen if the same user clicked several times on the button?

Comment: Ok, server it is. It's tagged with SQL related stuff because I figured I needed a server. Should I be looking into J2EE?


Multiple clicks? Would that be best handled on the app side or server side? In fact, I think I'd be able to craft it in such a way that multiple clicks is irrelevant or impossible.

Comment: Actually, I'm not even going to use a button. It will be based on iBeacon proximity... for which I'll have to make sure the data is only sent a single time. That shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: the most trivial server you can set up is using python flask or bottle, then set up a connection to any db server (does not have to be SQL, could be mongo or anything.) Google App engine, Heroku ... are some of the available hosting solution, a lot of PaaS (plateform as a service) have a free plan for small projects.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should be able to figure it out from here.